# Programmatically Work With Access Database On Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin, microsoft-access

I know that it is possible to upload Microsoft Access Databases to a Sharepoint server. I am needing a way to store a large amount of data on Sharepoint so that I can use it to to customize parts of the web page unique to each user based on data. My question is there any way to work with the Access database programatically through Javascript or some other method via a Sharepoint hosted app? Or alternatively a way to access an external SQL database from javascript? Thank you.